# Ascertaining a GET path

Tags: http

I am looking for some clarification on GET. If I have a URI such as `https://google.com/something/` and I try to access that webpage, web servers interpret this as a GET request for `/something/` rather than a GET for
`https://google.com/something/`? Server access logs will commonly only log the `/something/` part when visitors access the site. Yet, if I perform a curl on that full address, the internet tells me that curl is preforming a GET on the full URI. As such... what is the distinction here?

Also, what exactly does the shortened address, `/something/`,  represent? Is it a file that resides in the root of the website being accessed? What if I set up a rewrite for `/something/` to 301 to a particular address and `/something/` is not actually a file or directory; how is a request like that processed?

And lastly, is `https://username:password@google.com/` still the standard for accessing a website over https with http auth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Yet, if I perform a curl on that full address, the internet tells me that curl is preforming a GET on the full URI. As such... what is the distinction here?

The HTTP request sent would look like this:

```
GET /something/ HTTP/1.1
Host: google.com
...more HTTP headers here...
```

`curl` will show you what it's sending, add `-v`.

> Also, what exactly does the shortened address, /something/, represent? Is it a file that resides in the root of the website being accessed? What if I set up a rewrite for /something/ to 301 to a particular address and /something/ is not actually a file or directory; how is a request like that processed?

That's completely up to the server handling the request.  All the protocol dictates is that the client is asking for the content at that location - what the server responds with is completely up to the server's implementation.

> And lastly, is https://username:password@google.com/ still the standard for accessing a website over https with http auth?

This is one method of setting credentials to be used for basic auth; most HTTP clients will prompt for credentials if requested by the server.

Comment: So the request is delimited by a `/`? AKA. it trims off the FQDN at the beginning, then hits a `/` and everything after (and including) that `/` then becomes the body of the GET string that it attempts to source data via a connection to FQDN?

Comment: @Peter Right - your browser is handling chopping the string up to determine what server to connect to, what protocol to speak on which port (SSL or just HTTP), and what the request will be formatted as.